# Acceder a evento dentro de un control de un UserControll

Tags: c#, usercontrol

necesito acceder al evento click de un control que esta dentro de un UserControll que he añadido a mi proyecto.
¿Es posible hacerlo?
Gracias.
El UserControl no es mio, esta generado por una extensión de Sage.

```
public partial class txtprovaDesdeHasta : txtFiltroBase
{

    public txtprovaDesdeHasta()
    {
        this._Init();
    }

    /// <param name="tlEditando"></param>
    public txtprovaDesdeHasta(bool tlEditando = false)
        : base(tlEditando)
    {
        this._Init();
    }
    public override void _Init()
    {
        base._Init();

        _VariableFiltro = "prova";

        this._oFiltroDesde = new txtprova();
        this._oFiltroHasta = new txtprova();

        _Parametrizacion_Demorada();
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ewRecuadro1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // _oFiltroDesde
        // 
        this._oFiltroDesde._CrearManteSiCodigoNoExiste = false;
        this._oFiltroDesde.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(156, 21);
        this._oFiltroDesde.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(330, 25);
        this._oFiltroDesde.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // _oFiltroHasta
        // 
        this._oFiltroHasta._CrearManteSiCodigoNoExiste = false;
        this._oFiltroHasta.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(445, 21);
        this._oFiltroHasta.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(237, 25);
        this._oFiltroHasta.TabIndex = 7;

        // 
        // ewRecuadro1
        // 
        this.ewRecuadro1.Controls.Add(this.ewchkboxTodos);
        this.ewRecuadro1.Controls.Add(this.btBrowserLista);
        this.ewRecuadro1.Controls.Add(this.ewlabelDesde);
        this.ewRecuadro1.Controls.Add(this.ewlabelHasta);
        this.ewRecuadro1.Controls.Add(this._oFiltroDesde);
        this.ewRecuadro1.Controls.Add(this._oFiltroHasta);
        this.ewRecuadro1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.ewRecuadro1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 58);

        // 
        // ewchkboxTodos
        // 
        this.ewchkboxTodos._PropiedadesDeEstilos._ColorUnderlineEntering = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(88)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(163)))));
        this.ewchkboxTodos._PropiedadesDeEstilos._ColorUnderlineSelected = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(130)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
        this.ewchkboxTodos.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
        this.ewchkboxTodos.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 22);
        this.ewchkboxTodos.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(63, 21);
        this.ewchkboxTodos.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // txtprovaDesdeHasta
        // 
        this._ModoVisual = sage.ew.txtbox.Clases.ewFiltro.ModoVisual.Listados;
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ewRecuadro1);
        this.Name = "txtprovaDesdeHasta";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 58);
        this.ewRecuadro1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ewRecuadro1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

No consigo ver como están declarados los controles, me temo que se debe definir en la clase base :txtFiltroBase.

He eliminado del codigo la definición de varios controles, ya que si no no me deja publicarlo, el que me interesa es el checkbox "ewchkboxTodos", pero supongo que de ser posible, la solución sería extensible a todos los controles.
Decir que este UserControl lo tengo en un formulario y necesito acceder en este formulario al evento CheckedChanged del CheckBox mencionado.
Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Entiendo que en ese caso no tienes el codigo fuente del usercontrol, es asi? En ese caso veo dos opciones:  o el boton es publico, con lo que el acceso es sencillo, o si no deberás usar reflection para acceder al mismo. Es un poco complejo ayudarte mas sin tener acceso al mismo y poder estudiarlo.

Comment: Si fuera publico, debería poder acceder a el desde el formulario como txtprovaDesdeHasta.ewchkboxTodos verdad ?

Comment: De todas maneras..no entiendo muy bien todavía. Si quieres tener acceso a `ewchkboxTodos`, y por lo que veo tienes acceso a `txtprovaDesdeHasta`...pq no defines como `public` ese control?

Comment: Comprendo que no me entiendas, ya que soy un zoquete en proceso de aprendizaje. En cuanto a lo de definir el control como public, sinceramente, no veo donde hacerlo :_ Por cierto no puedo acceder a esos controles desde un objeto de tipo txtprovaDesdeHasta

Comment: No hombre, no es eso, y todos hemos sido mas o menos novatos en su momento :) La cosa es que nosotros no tenemos acceso a tu proyecto y no podemos ver exactamente cual es el problema. Tal vez deberías o bien explicar perfectamente la jerarquía en tu proyecto (formulario propio, usercontrol, checkbox) especificando si tienes acceso al codigo fuente/designer de los mismos. Alternativamente, si puedes crear un [mcve] tambien seria de ayuda.

Comment: Si tienes acceso al diseñador de la control `txtprovaDesdeHasta`, simplemente puedes seleccionar el checkbox y en las propiedades busca "modifiers". Ahi puedes poner public o private

Comment: Modifiers me aparece deshabilitado y como Protected.